# CSS background color when there is an image present

Tags: css, colors, background

I would like to have a color hidden behind the backgroun image so that when a user visits my site without the ability to view images or choose not to view images get a fairly consistent site. I have tried adding the color before and after the image but the color goes over my image. i have even tried using a color after the image, however the color colorizes the whole site background under everything.

```
.headerWrapper {
    background: url(../images/headerBG.png) repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.header {
    height:94px;
    width:1000px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing about the color in your css. Also it doesn't show us anything without html part

Comment: I guess, since the code isn't complete nor the question is clear, that you can use `background-color` property, or you can simply add the color in the background property, something like `background: url(../images/headerBG.png) black repeat-x;`. Next time try to create a fiddle so others can see your code working.

Comment: <div class="headerWrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear as to the code that you have tried. But you should use the `background-image` and `background-color` CSS properties, as declaring `background` twice will overwrite any of the others

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/nuwa2yLn/))

```
.headerWrapper {
    background-image: url(../images/headerBG.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: rgb(50,150,250);
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Or include the color in the background line

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/fh6v5ksm/))

```
.headerWrapper {
    background: url(../images/headerBG.png) rgb(50,150,250) repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: i have tried adding the code however if i add it after the image on a separate line it creates the color all throughout the background and not just in the header area hidden behind the image and showing on no image or image denied browsers, and if i put it on the same line as the image the color goes over the image. what i want to do should be simple enough. i just want the color to be behind the image not seen if the visitor sees images. and only shown when visitors have images off

Comment: If i add the color to the header wrapper section it covers the image to certain px % if i add the color to the header section, it goes behind the image, but continues thoughout the entire site, i just need the color to extend a certain size, for each section. the headerBG image is 94 pixels in size. i need the color to only be 94 pixels in the header however if it went a tad below to cover the banner images under the header image that would save me adding code for that section, that section is around 380px